# Connect accdb database using asp-classic

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic

Im trying to connect a database to my webpage using asp-classic. I was successful before when i was using a .mdb file but now i have a new database that is in the format of accdb and needs to be because of a feature that is not supported in the .mdb file.

The code i used for the .mdb connection that worked perfectly.

```
<%@Language=VBScript %>
<%
Dim adoCon
Dim rsLogbook
Dim strSQL
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.mdb")
Set rsLogbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT TableName.FieldName FROM TableName;"
rsLogbook.Open strSQL, adoCon
Response.Write ("<br>")
Response.Write (rsLogbook("FieldName"))
rsLogbook.Close
Set rsLogbook = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing
%>
```

I tried replacing the ".mdb" with "accdb" but no luck. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007) is usually a pretty good place to start when looking for the right syntax for a database connection.

Where did you change ".mdb" to ".accdb"? Did you do the following?

```
adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.accdb")
```

**Edit:**

After viewing the error (**"Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'"**) it seems like this KB Article might explain the issue and workaround: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926939

Comment: adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.accdb") Took out the ".mdb"

Comment: [here's a link to the test site](http://users9.jabry.com/obdkey/Featuredvehicle.asp)

Comment: i changed the code to what you have on your answer and uploaded to the test site

Comment: The articles for when im using IIS which im not but i did try it out in the end and still no luck :(